# Click event for new element created from jquery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, event-binding

I create a new div from post response. This div has a button and I want to assign a click event to it. It doesn't work if I the script part is in the response

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('test1');
        $('#next2').click(function(){
            alert('test2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

`alert('test1') works`, `test2` on click doesn't bind

Binding only works if put in `$.post(...)`.always `(function..)` but I'd like to have the binding in the same place as the rest of the loaded element to be flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need event delegation for dynamically created element.use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click','#next2',function(){
        alert('test2');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) with document scope for a dynamically created elements

```
  $(document').on('click',''#next2',function(){
        alert('test2');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target a dynamically added element you'll have to use

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#next2').on("click",function()
                alert('test2');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#next2').bind('click',function(){
        alert('test2');
});
<script>
```